# Subset csv data based on Pentad dates using R

Tags: r, csv, subset

I would like to subset the following csv file based on Pentad dates (non overlapping average of dates). For example:

```
1.January 1 to January 5
2.January 6 to January 10
...
73.December 27 to December 31.
```

Here's the complete list of pentad dates:

[List of Pentad dates](http://www.hysk.sakura.ne.jp/meteorol/misc/pentad.pdf)

[The Complete Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8U0k2TnVwTG9lYVE/view?usp=sharing)

Sample Data

```
SN,CY,Y,M,D,H,lat,lon,cat
198305,5,1983,8,5,0,9.1,140.7,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,6,9.3,140.5,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,12,9.6,139.9,"TD"
198305,5,1983,8,5,18,9.9,139.4,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,0,10.2,138.8,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,6,11,138.1,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,12,11.8,137.3,"TS"
198305,5,1983,8,6,18,12.4,136.4,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,0,12.8,135.8,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,6,13.6,134.7,"Cat1"
198305,5,1983,8,7,12,14.4,133.9,"Cat2"
198305,5,1983,8,7,18,15,133.5,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,0,15.8,132.8,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,6,16.3,132.4,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,8,12,17.1,132,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,8,18,17.4,131.4,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,9,0,17.8,130.8,"Cat5"
198305,5,1983,8,9,6,18.1,130.7,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,9,12,18.7,130.3,"Cat4"
198305,5,1983,8,9,18,18.9,130.4,"Cat4
```

SN is a unique identifier, Y is years, M is months, D is days,H is hours. If the unique number falls in one pentad, it should not be included in the next subset anymore.

I have tried this for August (based from previous post):

```
P1  <- c(1,6,11,16,21,26)
P6  <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30)
res <- Map(function(x,y) subset(df1, M==8 & D >=x & D <= y), d1, d2)
```

But I'm having a problem with mapping with the starting pentads (P7) because it includes January 31 to February 4.

Can anyone suggest any methods to do this in R? Ill appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
df$Date = paste(df$Y, str_pad(df$M,2,'left','0'), str_pad(df$D,2,'left','0'), sep='-')
# Extract day of year (int 0 to 365) from POSIXlt date
df$yday = as.POSIXlt(df$Date)$yday + 1
```

Now it's trivial:

```
df$pentad = ceiling(df$yday/5)
```

Comment: I tried this, but im not sure if this is the right way or there still simpler method than this (sample for aug to sep). I took advantage of the "day of year" from your code. What does the last line df$pentad do?                                                                                   d1 <-c(216,221,226,231,236,241,246,251,256,261,266)                              d2 <-c(220,225,230,235,240,245,250,255,260,265,270)                                                                                  res <- Map(function(x,y) subset(df, yday >=x & yday <= y),d1, d2)
lapply(res, head, 2)

Comment: To get the subsets just do `split(df, df$pentad)`. That gives you a list of dataframes, each corresponding to a pentad.

Comment: I just noticed double counting in the output. Is it possible to flag the unique id's such that when it was already counted in the previous pentad, it will not be counted in the next pentad anymore?

Comment: Here's the data that I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9faET7Bc2o8NnUybEVUVWp3cTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe try this: `dfuniq = unique(df[,c('SN','pentad')]); dfuniq = dfuniq[!duplicated(dfuniq$SN),];  df = merge(df, dfuniq)`.  Then `split`.

Comment: I see. Many Many thanks again for the help. Its working now. :-)